# Using parallel computing for two for loops

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

In my program(in matlab) I have two for loops and I want to use parallel computing for these loops:

```
#loop a
for i=1:120000
using var2(from the previous iteration (loop b)) and do something
and make var1
end;
#loop b
for j=1:120000
using var1(from the previous iteration(loop a)) and do something
and make var2
end;
```

my computer is dual core.can anyone help me?

Comment: you you tried to merge both loops to one and then use `parfor` instead of `for` - do you get any speedup?

Answer (score 1):

Parallel computing can only be performed if the variables used are independent. There are ways to get the variables to be independent, though that might not be the case. In your case, it doesnt seem like it, as the variables require the input of the previous variables from other loops.